# Amazon CloudSearch weight single field value

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-cloudsearch

I am working with Amazon CloudSearch in .NET and I have it working, however I would like to tweak the result and I'm not sure how to do it.  I have one field that is a list of id's; it stores what set's of objects it's a part of which can include a user 'favorites' object.

What I want to do is prioritize the results that reside in that favorites list so that they come up first.

I know that you can boost a field using the ^2 (or whatever value) but I want to prioritize a value in a field, is that possible?  Can you tell CloudSearch to 'match any of these values but prioritize matching this value'?

**Edit**

What I ended up doing on the advice of [alexroussos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255142/alexroussos) was to create a new filed in CloudSearch called 'favoritedusers' that holds the ID's of the users who have marked it as a favorite.  I then boost that for the current user in my search query so I end up with a query something like this (search term of 'back'):

(or (prefix 'back') (and (prefix 'back') (term field=favoritedusers boost=1.5 '9219cfe5-9756-45e7-ae15-b5ca73748404')))

This seems to be working pretty well in my testing and doing what I want it to do.

Comment: If the equality operator works for strings, you could use a custom ranking expression. It may only work for dates and numbers but the docs don't really say so you'd have to test it out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-expressions.html

Comment: Maybe a better idea would be to have an additional search term that searches only in the `favorites` and boost that

Comment: ok thank you, i will investigate those options and come back with results...

Comment: Added the resolution I came to based on your second comment.  If you make it an answer I will accept it...